# Call APIs from IIS to SQL Server. Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

Now, I publish .NET Core API on IIS after I test call APIs then I receive notice such as Login failed for user 'sa'.

I changed configure connect to SQL Server but still old notice. Please helpe me.[This is source I publish on IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWeK5.png)

[I also changed Identity is LocalSystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lK4J.png)

Comment: Why is IIS using the `sa` account in the first place? it should be using a `LOGIN`, with mapped `USER`s, with significantly lower permissions. Though if you want the true authentication error, check the SQL Server logs. If you don't understand that error, [edit] your question with said error, and explain what you don't understand.

Comment: This is related with your connection string, if you are using the connection string account sa, you should make sure the password is right. Besides, as Larnu said, we don't suggest you use the sa account.